# Apply discount for price steps

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, coupon

On Magento 1, I can create a promotion to apply a discount with a discount step quantity. How can I create a discount for price steps?

For example:
every 500$ of 50$ discount.

```
501$ = Total 451$
1020$ = Total 920$
1300$ = Total 1200$
etc.
```

Comment: If you want to do this from admin only then you need to create multiple cart rules.

Comment: Ok, but this is very cumbersome and limits the possibilities to a reduced range, I do not think that making 50 rules is useful.
Do you know a module that does this?

Comment: @mehdi has already submit the answer with suggestion of third party module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This extension will do it for you:

M1: https://amasty.com/special-promotions.html
M2: https://amasty.com/special-promotions-for-magento-2.html

then use Get $Y for each $X spent.